# How to create On load Event or default event in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am new to shiny as well as stackoverflow and looking for some help with a problem that I am currently stuck at.
I am trying to build a shiny app which collects some inputs from the user and creates visualization based on inputs on click of a button. Currently, that works fine, but one of the major ask is that, when the app loads for the first time, it shall have visualization prepared based on the default inputs.

I am pasting a sample code, which can explain the issue I am facing:

## UI.R

```
  #loading shiny
  library(shiny)
  
  ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Iris Dataset"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("x", "Select X-axis:",
                     list("Sepal.Length"='a', "Sepal.Width"='b', "Petal.Length"='c', "Petal.Width"='d')),
        radioButtons("y", "Select Y-axis:",
                     list("Sepal.Length"='e', "Sepal.Width"='f', "Petal.Length"='g', "Petal.Width"='h')),
        actionButton("action","Submit")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  ))
  
  #SERVER.R
  library(shiny)
  
  #loading shiny
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$action,{
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({if(input$x=='a'){i<-1}
      
      if(input$x=='b'){i<-2}
      
      if(input$x=='c'){i<-3}
      
      if(input$x=='d'){i<-4}
      
      if(input$y=='e'){j<-1}
      
      if(input$y=='f'){j<-2}
      
      if(input$y=='g'){j<-3}
      
      if(input$y=='h'){j<-4}
      
      s    <- iris[, i]
      k    <- iris[, j]
      plot(s,k)
    })
  })
  })
  
  
  shinyApp(ui<-ui, server<-server)
```

Now if you run this app, you would see that the inputs are selected at the first screen after load (which is as desired) but the visualization appears only after clicking "Submit" button, this is because of the observer event. **In the actual app, there are calculation being performed after capturing the inputs at the click of the button. Hence, the calculation triggers only when the actionButton is clicked**

**Is there a way, we can still keep the "Submit" button and its observe event, but automatically trigger the visualization or the action performed within the observe event at the start i.e. when the app loads for the first time.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `renderPlot` or other render functions inside `observeEvent` is considered bad practice. What you are looking for is a reactive object that represents the plot parameters. You can then access this reactive object inside your `renderPlot` context. Here is an example

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Dataset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("x", "Select X-axis:",
                   list("Sepal.Length" = 'a', "Sepal.Width" = 'b',
                        "Petal.Length" = 'c', "Petal.Width" = 'd')),
      radioButtons("y", "Select Y-axis:",
                   list("Sepal.Length" = 'e', "Sepal.Width" = 'f', 
                        "Petal.Length" = 'g', "Petal.Width" = 'h')),
      actionButton("action", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  user_choice <- eventReactive(input$action,{
    if (input$x == 'a'){i <- 1}    
    if (input$x == 'b'){i <- 2}    
    if (input$x == 'c'){i <- 3}    
    if (input$x == 'd'){i <- 4}    
    if (input$y == 'e'){j <- 1}    
    if (input$y == 'f'){j <- 2}    
    if (input$y == 'g'){j <- 3}    
    if (input$y == 'h'){j <- 4}

    return(c(i, j))

    ## use ignoreNULL to fire the event at startup
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    uc <- user_choice()
    plot(iris[, uc[1]], iris[, uc[2]])
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The object `user_choice` will get updated whenever a user clicks the button *or* the app starts.

There is also an `ignoreNULL` parameter in `observeEvent` but for some reason, that does not yield the same result.

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer. Just to clarify, I am using observe event because, once the inputs are captured, some calculations are performed, which then yields the parameters required for plot. But I understand your point and will try to use the approach and will post the results.

Comment: Why would somebody say that `observeEvent` is a bad practice? Is simply a particular function with particular results and it is very useful with buttons, for example. These are the kind of answers that confuse new people.

Comment: My statment was that using render functions inside `observeEvent` is bad practice, not that `observeEvent` should be avoided altogether. You can read up on the newest reference documentation of `observeEvent` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

just set the data for plot in `reactiveValues()` with a default value corresponding to the default plot during page load... by doing this, the plot shows up during load with the default data, and every time actionbutton is clicked the plot gets updated...

```
  server<-function(input, output) {

data1 = reactiveValues(plot=default_data)

observeEvent(input$action,{
    data1$plot = new_data
})

renderPlot({
      plot(..., data1$plot)
})
```

}