# RShiny: how can I activate a reactive expression once on startup

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Below I made a small example of an app that allows the user to select two variables from the `diamonds` dataset. The selected variables are returned by a `textOutput()` after activating an `actionButton()`.

I can select default inputs for the two `selectizeInput()` field, which I did. However, these default inputs are not return in the `textOutput()` field, because that is waiting for the `actionButton()` to be activated.

My question is: how can I run the reactive expression `text1Reactive <- eventReactive()` once on startup, and then have it update every time the `actionButton()` is clicked?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("xVar","Select X-variable",colnames(diamonds),selected='carat'),
  selectizeInput("yVar","Select Y-variable",colnames(diamonds),selected='cut'),
  actionButton("go","Update variables"),
  textOutput("text1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  text1Reactive <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    paste("X =",input$xVar,". Y =",input$yVar)
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    text1Reactive()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894343/how-to-create-on-load-event-or-default-event-in-shiny) they introduce `ignoreNULL = FALSE`

Comment: That's very quick and works right away, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it help, don't forget to upvote that answer. Thanks.